# Blazorise RTE validations

Tags: validation, rich-text-editor, blazorise

I have a rich text editor from blazorise and I am trying to validate the input a user is writing. Specifically to not be empty. I have created a TextEdit invisible component in order to get that message, but it seems that my validation on textedit to not be triggered. I have a fluentvalidations check, and is not a form.

Here is what I am doing:

```
<FieldLabel>Viber message:</FieldLabel>
                                <RichTextEdit @ref="rteViberBody"
                                              ContentChanged="@MyCheckRTEMethod"
                                              PlaceHolder="Type your message here..."
                                              ReadOnly="@readOnly"
                                              SubmitOnEnter="false"
                                              Style="height:80px">
                                    <Editor>
                                       
                                    </Editor>
                                    <Toolbar>
                                        <RichTextEditToolbarGroup Float="Float.End">                                               
                                            <RichTextEditToolbarButton Action="RichTextEditAction.Bold" />
                                            <RichTextEditToolbarButton Action="RichTextEditAction.Italic" />
                                            <RichTextEditToolbarButton Action="RichTextEditAction.Strike" />
                                            <RichTextEditToolbarButton Action="RichTextEditAction.Image" />
                                            <RichTextEditToolbarButton Action="RichTextEditAction.Clean" />
                                        </RichTextEditToolbarGroup>
                                    </Toolbar>
                                </RichTextEdit>
                            </Field>
                        </Fields>
                        <Fields>
                            <Field>
                                <Validation AsyncValidator="@ValidateRTEViberInputAsync">
                                    <TextEdit @bind-Text="viberMessageHiddenForValidation" @bind-Text:event="oninput" Visibility="Visibility.Invisible">
                                            <Feedback>
                                            <ValidationError>Please type a message.</ValidationError>
                                        </Feedback>
                                    </TextEdit>
                                </Validation>
                            </Field>
```

Has someone has a clue of what needs to be done or change in order to make it work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. I'm having the same problem but with another field, a custom that I made. Did you make this work? I'm struggling for one day already.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found that this is proposed: https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/issues/1792

So far there's a workaround but not very nice:

```
<RichTextEdit @ref="richTextEditRef"
                ConfigureQuillJsMethod="blazoriseDemo.configureQuillJs"
                ContentChanged="@OnContentChanged"
                Border="@( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( contentAsText ) ? Border.Danger : null)">
      ...
  </RichTextEdit>
  @if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( contentAsText ) )
  {
      <Paragraph TextColor="TextColor.Danger">Text is empty</Paragraph>
  }
  else
  {
      <Paragraph TextColor="TextColor.Success">Text is valid</Paragraph>
  }
@code{
    private string contentAsText;

    public async Task OnContentChanged()
    {
        contentAsText = await richTextEditRef.GetTextAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A workaround for that if someone faces something similar, go check [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/issues/1792#issuecomment-1369741666) posted by [stsrki](https://github.com/stsrki), which suggests the following code:

```
<RichTextEdit @ref="richTextEditRef"
                ConfigureQuillJsMethod="blazoriseDemo.configureQuillJs"
                ContentChanged="@OnContentChanged"
                Border="@( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( contentAsText ) ? Border.Danger : null)">
      ...
  </RichTextEdit>
  @if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( contentAsText ) )
  {
      <Paragraph TextColor="TextColor.Danger">Text is empty</Paragraph>
  }
  else
  {
      <Paragraph TextColor="TextColor.Success">Text is valid</Paragraph>
  }
@code{
    private string contentAsText;

    public async Task OnContentChanged()
    {
        contentAsText = await richTextEditRef.GetTextAsync();
    }
}
```